# React and chart.js with json

Tags: json, reactjs, chart.js

I'm very new in React and JS. I'm trying to create a graph from JSON, but I can't pass value to graph with MAP function and PUSH, my result is just numbers that I put manually (2, 3, 5 - Line 45)

```
dataGraf.push(hit.minutos) //Works well

this.state.items.map((hit) => (dataGraf.push(hit.minutos))) //No erros, but no data add
```

My JSON:

```
[
  {"indice":1,"minutos":569,"programa":"seg"}, 
  {"indice":2,"minutos":421,"programa":"ter"}, 
  {"indice":3,"minutos":258,"programa":"quar"}
]
```

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Chart from "chart.js";
import Config from '../components/config.js';

let dataGraf = []

class GraphChart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myRef = React.createRef();

        this.state = {
            items: [],
            error: null
        };
      }

  componentDidMount() {
    let url1 = `${Config.FullURL}/progativo`
    const ctx = this.ctx;

    fetch(url1)
      .then(items => items.json())
      .then((items) => {
        this.setState({ items });
      });

      this.funDadosGrafico()

    new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "pie",
        data: {
          labels: ['blue', 'green','red'],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "# of Likes",
              data: dataGraf
            }                
          ]
        }
      });
    } //End of componentDidMount

    funDadosGrafico(){
      dataGraf.push(2, 5, 3) //Just for test
      this.state.items.map((hit) => (
        dataGraf.push(hit.minutos)))
    }

    render() {
      return (
          <div>
              <canvas width='800' height='300' ref={ctx => (this.ctx = ctx)}/>
          </div>
      )
    }
}
export default GraphChart;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try moving the execution this.funDadosGrafico() and Canvas creation to componentDidUpdate.

once you call fetch, fetch wont block the thread, hence this.funDadosGrafico() is executed right aftwards. `then` blocks are executed only after fetch is resolved.

plus, setState method is also async. it is not going to work as expected even if you remove setState from fetch call like:

```
this.setState(updateMyState)
this.funDadosGrafico() // not going to work also, setState is async
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!
I need studie about sync and async
Thanks so much